# getting error in "delete CDocManager::pStaticDocManager;"

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

While running following code

```
if (CDocManager::pStaticDocManager != NULL)
  {
   delete CDocManager::pStaticDocManager;
   CDocManager::pStaticDocManager = NULL;
  }
```

exception "Unhandled exception at 0x0041f09d in ChinaEncrypter.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00003130" is coming in delete statement.

**Note:**This error is coming only in release mode and pStaticDocManager is initialising only in release mode. In debug mode it is having NULL value during whole process.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no need to check for NULL, `delete` does it automatically

Comment: Can you step into the framework source for the CDocManager destructor? Also open the Exceptions window (Ctrl+E) and break when Win32 exceptions are thrown. Try to get a little closer to the source of the access violation.

Comment: Is that your code cleaning up the static doc manager, or framework code?

Answer (score 0):

Did you explicit initialize pStaticDocManager to NULL ?

Also make sure the instance pointed by pStaticDocManager have all its member correctly initialized.

Comment: No I have not initialised it explicitly.While calling SHBrowseForFolder(&binfo) it is getting initialised.